# lxml converts "<" to &lt;. Why?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I've stared me blind on this problem.

I'm fedding XML-encapsulated HTML-data into Atlassian Confluence. For the -tags I need to add a span-tag. But no matter how I try, lxml-lib converts my < and > into < and > respectively. But, the conversion is only for my new tags, any existing tag within the  gets its characted untouched!

Have a look at this Python-code:

```
for x in doc.iter():
    if x.tag == "td":
        print x.text
        x.text = "no tags"
        print etree.dump(x)
        x.text = "<span>one tag</span>"
        print etree.dump(x)
```

For this input:

```
<tr>
  <td>apa</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://korv.com/apa.tar.gz">3.4</a>
  </td>
  <td>no</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>coreutils</td>
  <td>6.12</td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.21.tar.xz">8.21</a>
  </td>
  <td>no</td>
</tr>
```

This is the output:

```
<td>no tags</td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;</td>None
1.2
<td>no tags</td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;</td>None
None
<td>no tags<a href="http://korv.com/apa.tar.gz">3.4</a></td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;<a href="http://korv.com/apa.tar.gz">3.4</a></td>None
no
<td>no tags</td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;</td>None
coreutils
<td>no tags</td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;</td>None
6.12
<td>no tags</td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;</td>None
None
<td>no tags<a href="http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.21.tar.xz">8.21</a></td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;<a href="http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.21.tar.xz">8.21</a></td>None
no
<td>no tags</td>None
<td>&lt;span&gt;one tag&lt;/span&gt;</td>None
```

As you can see the -tag within is untouched, while my  is converted. I cannot grasp this error.

Why is the conversion done for my text while it's untouched for the existing?

Answer (score 5):

You are inserting *text* into an XML element. Text always will be escaped to be XML-safe.

If you wanted to add a new tag, create a new `Element`; the [`ElementTree.SubElement()` factory](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#SubElement) is easiest:

```
from lxml import etree

etree.SubElement(td, 'span').text = 'one tag'
```

If you wanted to *wrap* the contents of the `td`, simply move all elements over (plus the `.text` attribute:

```
def wrap(parent, tagname, **kw):
    sub = etree.SubElement(parent, tagname, **kw)
    parent.text, sub.text = None, parent.text
    for index, child in enumerate(parent.iterchildren()):
        if child is not sub:
            sub.insert(index, child)
    return parent

wrap(td, 'span')
```

Demo:

```
>>> etree.tostring(doc.findall('.//td')[2])
'<td>\n    <a href="http://korv.com/apa.tar.gz">3.4</a>\n  </td>\n  '
>>> etree.tostring(wrap(tree.findall('.//td')[2], 'span'))
'<td><span>\n    <a href="http://korv.com/apa.tar.gz">3.4</a>\n  </span></td>\n  '
```

Comment: Good point. I have yet to find how to add this new tag, surrounding all the contents of the td-tag. That is: <td>foo</td> => <td><span>foo</span></td>. It works out of the box for plain text, but fail horribly when the <td> contans other tags, like <a>, <br>, etc.

Comment: @bos: You can use `span.insert(index, elem)` on the new `span` element to *move* existing elements into the span. Combine that with looping over the existing children of the `td` and you'll be able to move all elements into a span in no time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
x.text = "<span>one tag</span>"
```

you are saying that the content of the node is that text. Since `<` and `>` are reserved characters in XML, they need to be escaped.

It looks like you are trying to create new `<span>` nodes and to do that you will have to create the nodes.